# Styling new rows with jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables plugin and adding new rows after passing data back from AJAX via JSON.

The data is adding fine however I want all columns except column 2 to have padding-top: 14px however my code, for some reason, is only applying this to the first row that is added.

```
$( data['table_data'] ).each(function( index, domEle) {

var a = oTable.fnAddData( [
    domEle['rownum'],
    domEle['logo'],
    domEle['total_impressions'],
    domEle['total_clicks'],
    domEle['ecpm'],
    domEle['total_media_cost'],
    domEle['total_media_cost_diff'],
    domEle['total_spend'],
    domEle['total_spend_diff']

]);

var nTr = oTable.fnSettings().aoData[ a[0] ].nTr;
$('td:eq(0),td:eq(2),td:eq(3),td:eq(4),td:eq(5),td:eq(6),td:eq(7),td:eq(8)').css('padding-top', '10px');

});
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to make it apply to every row?

Cheers

Comment: Will you be adding/removing rows to this DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td:not(:eq(1))").css({
        'padding-top': '14px',
        'color': 'blue'
    });
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypcHL/)

Comment: Cheers, I found something pretty similar just before your reply.